# I want to match md5 value with table column like md5(id) = $id in phalcon

Tags: md5, phalcon

I am getting stuck with matching md5 value with table column and can't find even phalcon document.

if have md5 encrypted value that i want to match with table id(int) column.

Comment: So, what error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have db column encrypted in md5 like you stored your password in md5
then you can do

```
$password="abc";
$phql = "SELECT * FROM users where password=:password:";
$result= $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql,array('password'=>md5($password));
```